# Problema ao instalar o Flutter

Tags: mobile, flutter

ao digitar o comando `flutter doctor` no cmd é exibido o seguinte erro:

> **Error**: The Flutter directory is not a clone of the GitHub project. The flutter tool requires Git in order to operate properly; to set up
> Flutter, run the following command: `git clone -b stable https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git`

Eu já mudei as variáveis do path de instalação, já reinstalei o git e nada funcionou, já executei o comando de dentro da pasta e infelizmente nada aconteceu. Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Comment: Ele está reclamando que o Git não está buscando um clone e tal. Não utilizo o Git por isso não sei como resolver, mas recomendo que procure algo do tipo e veja se há alguma configuração automática ativa e tente um outro editor (MS Code ou Android Studio) e veja se o mesmo acontece. Veja também se no windows há uma configuração armazenada em disco com relação a algum editor ou extensão que utiliza o Git e tente excluir.

Comment: Uma boa dica é utilizar o FVM - Flutter Version Management, com ele fica bem mais fácil o processo de instalação do Git e de diversas versões do Flutter, bastante setar qual é a versão que deseja utilizar em determinado momento. Fica a dica, entre em www.fvm.app, um bom começo é assistir um vídeo do Jacob Moura em https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GSamxnXIRhg.

Answer (score 7):

O Flutter procura por uma pasta git que normalmente é pasta oculta. Se você usou o modo copiar/colar do arquivo zip pode ser que esta pasta tenha sido perdida.

Você pode resolver copiando a pasta externa do flutter para incluir todos os arquivos ocultos ou executar o comando que o erro passa, que é:

```
git clone -b stable https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
```

E o caminho que segui para instalação foi:

1 - Download do sdk no [site oficial](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install)

2 - Extrair o arquivo (renomeei a pasta apenas para flutter) e colocar em um local preferencialmente sem a necessidade de privilégios. - O meu fica em C:\flutter

3 - Adicionar nas váriaveis do ambiente o caminho C:\flutter\bin ou o caminho que você selecionar para manter o sdk

Answer (score 1):

Como voce fez a instalação do flutter?

Verifica se tua versão tá atualizada.

Usa o comando `flutter upgrade` para pegar a última versão estável.

Caso necessário, remove a instalação já feita e executa uma nova instalação.

Baixa o SDK direto no site https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows
, depois extrai o arquivo zip dentro de C:/src/flutter, como a Google recomenda e executa o arquivo **flutter_console**.

Se executar sem problemas, adiciona a pasta C:\src\flutter\bin ao PATH de variáveis de ambiente.

Lembrando que é preciso ter o git instalado na máquina.